# how to change this form into responsive

Tags: forms, responsive-design

Hi in the below code I am displaying login form.No everything was working fine but i want to be change this form as a responsive.

Can any one help me

**html**

```
<div class="login-01">
        <div class="one-login  hvr-float-shadow">
            <div class="one-login-head">
                    <img src="images/top-lock.png" alt=""/>
                    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
                    <span></span>
            </div>
            <form>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" class="text" value="Username" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" ><a href="#" class=" icon user"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"><a href="#" class=" icon lock"></a>
                </li>
                <div class="p-container">
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked><i></i>Remember Me</label>
                        <h6><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a> </h6>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="SIGN IN" >
                </div>

                    <h5>Don't have an account ?<a href="AdmissionForm.html"> Sign Up </a></h5>
                </form>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 1):

Provided you don't have any elements inside your .login-01 class with a fixed width, your form already is responsive. See http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/gbZrKj and change your browser width.

For best results you also want to include the following meta tag in the head of your web page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and you might need to include a CSS reset like http://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize

These last two steps may cause havoc with your page layout, but making an entire page responsive is another question.

Good luck!